# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting Error in view Page.
Its My Controller

```
using (wipoeeshetronEntities db = new wipoeeshetronEntities())
{
    var tbllogin = db.masteruserlogindet_tbl.Where(m => m.IsDeleted == 0).ToList();
    return View(tbllogin); 
}
```

It's My View:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.masterroledet_tbl.RoleDesc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "Using". The Controller has it's own dispose() method. Your new code would then be...

```
wipoeeshetronEntities db = new wipoeeshetronEntities()
var tbllogin = db.masteruserlogindet_tbl.Where(m => m.IsDeleted == 0).ToList();
return View(tbllogin);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

The object you are returning with the call to `View` is an ActionResult instance, which gets passed along further down the pipeline. However, because you are lazy-loading your entities (i.e. no Include or join on the masterroledet_tbl table), you are already out of the scope of the datacontext (in the `using` statement).

The solution is not to leave the context undisposed (this could cause memory leak issues), but to include/join the correct objects on your entities before leaving your MVC-action.